# CakePHP: calling function in the AppController

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How to call a function inside the app_controller.php in app/app_controller.php 
in the behavior of a plugin which is at app/plugins/media/models/behaviors/transfer.php   inside a method called transferTo.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling your app controller from a behavior in the first place. If you really must have access to your controller, then use a component

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't. Models and/or behaviors should not talk back to the controller. If the method is so universally usable, make it a function in `bootstrap.php`, put it in `AppModel` if it's applicable there or create your own utility class in `/app/libs` that you can call statically from anywhere.

<sub>(You *can* call `AppController::myMethod()` anywhere, provided you're in a normal request cycle where the `AppController` is already loaded, or use `ClassRegistry::init` to get an instance of *any* controller (which will have the method), but this'll probably create more problems than it solves. **Don't do this.**)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **requestAction()** for this. The requestAction is a way to call any controller function from any different controller.

The syntax is

```
$response = $this->requestAction('name of controller/action_name/'.$parameter);
```

you will get the result in $response variable.

Comment: **requestAction()**  is depreciated since CakePHP 3.4, please use other solutions such as View Cell. Following is the link to study View Cell [https://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/view-cell-cakephp-3-quick-start/]